# DOMParser is not parsing everything as expected

Tags: javascript, dom, document, domparser

i am new to javascript and webdevelopment . So i was planning to dynamically create an element . But i got stuck here.

I want to convert this raw string to DOM element , but domparser is not working as i expected or i am doing something wrong.
RAW STRING =

```
 <tr id="Desert Eagle | Hypnotic" onload="updateTABLE('Desert Eagle | Hypnotic', 'False', 'Field-Tested', 'Not Possible')">
    <th scope="row">
        <i class="fas fa-minus-circle stattrak" onclick="removeItem(individualprice0)"></i>
    </th>
    <th class="stattrak">Desert Eagle </th>
    <th> Hypnotic</th>
    <th class="stattrakvalue">
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" >
        <option class="st-options">False</option>
        <option class="st-options">True</option>
    </select>
    </th>
    <th>
        <select class="form-control 22" id="exampleFormControlSelect1"><option class="st-options">Factory New</option><option class="st-options">Minimal Wear</option><option class="st-options">Field-Tested</option><option class="st-options">Well-Worn</option><option class="st-options">Battle-Scarred</option></select>
    </th>
    <th id="individualprice0" class="individualprice">$47.87</th>
</tr>
```

I am trying to convert this to DOM Element .I TRIED :

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(resp[i].toString(),'text/html')
console.log(doc);
```

Response I GOT :

```
<html><head></head><body>
        
            <i class="fas fa-minus-circle stattrak" onclick="removeItem(individualprice0)"></i>
        
        Five-SeveN 
         Fowl Play
        
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option class="st-options">False</option>
            <option class="st-options">True</option>
        </select>
        
        
            <select class="form-control 22" id="exampleFormControlSelect1"><option class="st-options">Factory New</option><option class="st-options">Minimal Wear</option><option class="st-options">Field-Tested</option><option class="st-options">Well-Worn</option><option class="st-options">Battle-Scarred</option></select>
        
        $5.83
    
    
    </body></html>
```

Here in the response , you can see it is missing `<tr>` and `<th>` as well. While i parse them in xml everything works well tho.

Comment: `<tr>` is not valid outside a table. The DOM parser sanitises the invalid tags.

Comment: Damn ,I am such a stupid how could i not know that. Thankyou @VLAZ ,it really saved my day .